# How to change HashMap on SparseArray correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap, sparse-matrix

I changed:

```
private val map = HashMap<Int, AuthorizationContentView>()
```

on

```
private val map = SparseArray<AuthorizationContentView>()
```

But how can I fix the situation here?

```
val view = map.getOrPut(position) {
    AuthorizationContentView(context = context)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getOrPut` is an extension function in `MutableMap` You can do the same for `SparseArray` as well using your own custom extension function. That's how convenient Kotlin is :)

```
/**
 * Returns the value for the given key. If the key is not found in the SparseArray,
 * calls the [defaultValue] function, puts its result into the array under the given key
 * and returns it.
 */
public inline fun <V> SparseArray<V>.getOrPut(key: Int, defaultValue: () -> V): V {
    val value = get(key)
    return if (value == null) {
        val answer = defaultValue()
        put(key, answer)
        answer
    } else {
        value
    }
}
```